# Navigate with react-router-dom after useEffect-based setState

Tags: reactjs, react-router, local-storage, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I'm using [react-storage-hooks](https://github.com/soyguijarro/react-storage-hooks), which provides a way to have a global state using localStorage. Internally, it seems like calling a setValue function waits until the next render using useEffect. This is an issue because I want to set this local storage value and immediately navigate programmatically to a different page using [react-router-dom](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/).

Here is a simplified example

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useStorageState } from 'react-storage-hooks';

export function Example() {
  const history = useHistory();

  // I'm ignoring writeError as it isn't relevant for this example
  const [value, setValue, writeError] = useStorageState<string>(
    localStorage,
    'test',
    'initial value'
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Current Value: {value}</p>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          // Set value to a new value 
          // This operation is delayed until the next render with useEffect internally
          setValue('new value');
          // Navigate to a different page after setting the value
          history.push('/');
        }}
      >
        Click Me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I was thinking of having an extra useState variable called `navigateOut` so instead of directly calling `history.push()` I can simply call it on the next render with an `if (navigateOut) history.push();` call but that seems kind of messy.

This would probably be easier if setValue had some kind of callback/promise-based API but that doesn't seem to be the case. So I guess my question is, what is the idiomatic/hook-based approach to go about this?

EDIT: I realized I forgot to specify something in my example. I need to differentiate between simply modifying the value and modifying + navigating. As in, I should be able to setValue without redirecting unless I specify it to do so.

Comment: Use an `useEffect` hook with a dependency to issue a side-effect, like navigating to another route.

Comment: If you mean something like having an extra useState variable for a useEffect to navigate, that's what I was also thinking, but I'm not sure if that's the best approach. If instead you meant that I could have a useEffect depend on value and navigate on value change, then that wouldn't work because I'd like to be able to setValue without necessarily navigating out (see EDIT).

Comment: The former. You can have as many effects as necessary to get the functionality you need. The dependency would be the state value to "trigger" the navigation.

Comment: Okay, that's what I ended up doing and it worked. But isn't it kind of bad to have an extra useState variable + useEffect just to navigate out? Maybe that's just me.

Comment: I don't think so. You would have nearly the same in a class-based component; some callback sets state with new value and navigate trigger and you check the navigate trigger in `componentDidUpdate` to handle side-effect? Yes, you *can* use the `setState` callback but IMO this is an abuse of the function and removes logic from the lifecycle functions which can make tracing through a component more difficult. It also breaks the Single Responsibility Principle of the handler.

Comment: Hmm you are right. Thanks for the help! Is there a way to mark a comment as answer? Otherwise I'll just mark the the question itself as answered and mention it as an EDIT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setValue do have a kind of callback as mentioned in your comments, adding a use effect that only triggers when value changes will solve your problems

```
useEffect(() => {
history.push('/');
}, [value]); // This will only listen to changes on value
```

see https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: Sorry I might have oversimplified my example a bit. I already have a useEffect hook because I have multiple ways to modify the value. One of them redirects to a different page (this issue) but another has other side effects. So I need this to be different from simply modifying the value. As in, I need to differentiate a modification from a modification + navigation. Otherwise this would be the answer! (I'll mark this as answered once I get the answer for the EDIT, sorry).